# Convergence of a sequence definition explanation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have just started studying mathematical analysis and I need some help on the definition of convergence of a sequence.

I think I understand the definition of a sequence. I definitely understand what a metric space is.

The definition in Rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis) goes like this: "A sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to converge if there is a point $p \in X$ with the following property: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $d(p_n,p)<\epsilon$."

First of all I do not understand what for every $\epsilon$ means. Isn't it arbitrary? And then what does "there is an integer $N$" part mean, how do we assign $N$ for some arbitrary $\epsilon$? And then clearly I cannot understand implications.

Comment: Think of any small number you like ($\epsilon>0$) then there is some point along the sequence (there is an integer N) so that from that point onwards ($n\geq N$) all values of the sequence are no further from p than $\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to say "for every $\epsilon > 0$, ..." means that $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number. Think of it as a threshold. Then, given this choice of $\epsilon$, even if it's very very small, if $p_n \to p$ we want to be able to say that the sequence eventually gets so close to $p$ that the distance between the sequence elements $p_n$ and $p$ is negligible past some point, i.e., is smaller than our threshold $\epsilon$. This point is the $N$ that we need. It depends on $\epsilon$: generally, the tighter our requirements are (i.e., the smaller $\epsilon$ is), the greater we need $N$ to be in order for $p_n$ to be $\epsilon$-close to $p$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: So suppose  $\epsilon = 0.05$ and $p_n=1/n$ then what would N be. It says that N should be an integer. Oh it will be. Because our N would be very large rather than small. So N would be past the threshold or before it? I think immediately past it, right?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Well, here we know that $p = 0$, so we're looking for a $N$ such that $1/n < 0.05$ whenever $n \geq N$. But that's equivalent to $n > 1/0.05 = 20$, so we can take $N$ to be any integer $\geq 21$.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal If the threshold were even smaller, say $\epsilon = 0.01$, then we'd need to go further down the sequence: the same computation shows that we'd need to pick a $N \geq 101$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of convergence in a sequence is that if you tell me that $p_n$ converges to $p \in X$, no matter how close ($\epsilon > 0$) I ask you to get, you can always find an element of the sequence ($p_N$) such that all subsequent elements of the sequence ($p_n$ for $n \geq N$) are closer than that.  Does that help?

This should agree with your intuition and what you learned in calculus classes.

Answer (score 0):

Think for $\varepsilon$ as a measure of approximation. Then if $p_n$ converges to $p$, it means that there are an "instant" $N$ such that the terms $p_N, p_{N+1}, p_{N+2},...$ etc, all ought to be $\varepsilon$-close to the limit $p$.